# I want to bring the file from S3 to Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I want to bring the file from S3 to Elasticsearch
Help me
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have described in a little more details your use case, but with the little information you have given, here is what I would suggest.

Logstash provides the [`s3` input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html) which you can use to source data from an S3 bucket. Data from the files inside that bucket can then be sent to Elasticsearch using the Logstash [`elasticsearch` output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html)

The Logstash configuration file would look like this:

```
input {
  s3 {
    "access_key_id" => "1234"
    "secret_access_key" => "secret"
    "bucket" => "my-bucket"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "my-index"
  }
}
```

Another idea since you are in the AWS ecosystem would be to create a lambda that sources data from an S3 bucket and sends it directly to Elasticsearch. Here is an example on how to set this up: https://github.com/miztiik/serverless-s3-to-elasticsearch-ingester

Comment: thank you. Your idea is quite good.
Do you have any other way through logstask or any other tool.
only S3 -> elasticsearch - kibana

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution without Logstash